# SAPUI5 OData (with Navigation) in XML view & VizFrame Chart Navigation

Tags: javascript, xml, navigation, odata, sapui5

I’m developing a SAPUI5 application for my company and I’m having trouble with using OData (with Navigation) in XML based views. There have been a few posts about it about it but I just can’t get it to work with the expand property. (It works if I try it in Js based views)

Metadata.xml

```html
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

    <Schema Namespace="TEST_SRV" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">


      <EntityType Name="ISSUE_B">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="B" />

        </Key>
        <Property Name="B" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="NbI" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="K1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="I1" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="K2" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="I2" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />


        <NavigationProperty Name="B2AB_NAV" Relationship="TEST_SRV.B2AB_ASS" FromRole="FromRole_B2AB_ASS" ToRole="ToRole_B2AB_ASS" />

      </EntityType>

      <EntityType Name="ISSUE_AB">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="CId" />
          <PropertyRef Name="B" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="B" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="CId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="Open" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" Unicode="true" />
        <Property Name="Closed" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" Unicode="true" />

      </EntityType>

      <Association Name="B2AB_ASS">
        <End Type="TEST_SRV.ISSUE_B" Multiplicity="0..1" Role="FromRole_B2AB_ASS" />
        <End Type="TEST_SRV.ISSUE_AB" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_B2AB_ASS" />
        <ReferentialConstraint>
          <Principal Role="FromRole_B2AB_ASS">
            <PropertyRef Name="B" />
          </Principal>
          <Dependent Role="ToRole_B2AB_ASS">
            <PropertyRef Name="B" />
          </Dependent>
        </ReferentialConstraint>
      </Association>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="ODataWebV2.My.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="TEST_SRV_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">


        <EntitySet Name="ISSUE_BSet" EntityType="TEST_SRV.ISSUE_B" />
        <EntitySet Name="ISSUE_ABSet" EntityType="TEST_SRV.ISSUE_AB" />

        <AssociationSet Name="B2AB_ASSSet" Association="TEST_SRV.B2AB_ASS">
          <End EntitySet="ISSUE_BSet" Role="FromRole_B2AB_ASS" />
          <End EntitySet="ISSUE_ABSet" Role="ToRole_B2AB_ASS" />
        </AssociationSet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

View  ('myData' is my OData model which is defined in the manifest)

```html
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data" xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds"
  xmlns:suite="sap.suite.ui.commons" controllerName="test.controller.DetailView" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" height="100%">

  <Page id="detail1" title="{i18n>detailTitle}" showFooter="true" enableScrolling="false" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <content>

      <ObjectHeader title="{myData>B}" number="{myData>NbI}" numberUnit="{i18n>numberUnit}" />


      <suite:ChartContainer id="idChartContainer" showFullScreen="true" showPersonalization="false" autoAdjustHeight="false" showLegend="true">

        <suite:toolbar>
          <OverflowToolbar id="appToolbar">
            <suite:ChartContainerToolbarPlaceholder/>
          </OverflowToolbar>
        </suite:toolbar>
        <suite:content>
          <suite:ChartContainerContent icon="sap-icon://bar-chart" title="Column Chart">
            <suite:content>
              <viz:VizFrame uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" id="oVizFrame1" vizType="column" width="100%" selectData="onClickVizFrame">
                <viz:dataset>
                  <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{
                path:'myData>/ISSUE_BSet',
                parameters: {expand: 'B2AB_NAV'}
                }">
                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                      <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Customer" value="{myData>B2AB_NAV/CId}" />
                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                    <viz.data:measures>
                      <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Closed" value="{myData>B2AB_NAV/Closed}" />
                      <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Open" value="{myData>B2AB_NAV/Open}" />
                    </viz.data:measures>
                  </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                </viz:dataset>
                <viz:feeds>
                  <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Open" />
                  <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Closed" />
                  <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Customer" />
                </viz:feeds>
              </viz:VizFrame>

            </suite:content>
          </suite:ChartContainerContent>
        </suite:content>
      </suite:ChartContainer>

    </content>
    <footer>
      <Toolbar>
        <content>
          <ToolbarSpacer>
          </ToolbarSpacer>
          <Button id="__button1" icon="sap-icon://action" press="handlePopoverShare" />
        </content>
      </Toolbar>
    </footer>

  </Page>
</core:View>
```

Controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
      "test/controller/BaseController",
      "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
      "sap/ui/model/Filter",
      "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
    ], function(BaseController, JSONModel, Filter, FilterOperator) {
      "use strict";

      return BaseController.extend("test.controller.DetailView", {



          onInit: function() {

            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

            oRouter.getRoute("select").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

          },


          _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {

            var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
            var oView = this.getView();
            var oChart = oView.byId("oVizFrame2");

            oChart.bindElement({
              path: "/" + oArgs.domain,
              model: "myData",
              expand: "B2AB_NAV"
            });


            oView.bindElement({
              path: "/" + oArgs.domain,
              model: "myData",
              events: {
                change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                dataRequested: function(oEvent) {
                  oView.setBusy(true);
                },
                dataReceived: function(oEvent) {
                  oView.setBusy(false);
                }

              }
            });



          },
          _onBindingChange: function(oEvent) {

            // No data for the binding
            if (!this.getView().getBindingContext("myData")) {
              this.getRouter().getTargets().display("notFound");
            }
          },



          onClickVizFrame: function(oEvent) {


            var oItem = oEvent.getSource();

            // Get data 
            var clickedCol = oEvent.getSource().vizSelection()[0].data["_context_row_number"]
            var oChart = this.getView().byId("oVizFrame1");
            var aContexts = oChart.getDataset().getBinding("data").getContexts();
            var sPath = aContexts[clickedCol].getPath().substr(1); //selected binding context

            // Clear VizFrame Selection
            var action = {
              clearSelection: true
            };
            oItem.vizSelection("", action);

            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.navTo("detail", {
              data: sPath
            });

          },
          onNavBack: function() {
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.navTo("initial", true);
          }
        }
      });
```

Furthermore I would like to navigate into more detail by using a VizFrame chart but if I try to get the BindingContext path when clicking it only gives me the the Navigation path without the previous path.

Thanks in advance for helping :)

EDIT:

[Working plunker example](https://plnkr.co/EcOhlM5fRZAcPNXIxPHk)

As you can see when you navigate to the second page the first chart doesn't work (xml) but the second one (js) does. Navigating to the third page doesn't function either since the BindingContext is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed out the problems that you faced with and here is a link to modified plunker:

here is an example of "bindObject" method call (I leave it here, becasue stackoverflow does not allow to post the link to plnkr without coding, which is pretty weird to me.

```
  oView.bindObject({
    path: "/" + oArgs.data,
    model: "myData",
    parameters: {
      $expand: "B2AB_NAV"
    }
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/hTSvXk1811MKdUxqfQJn

In a nutshell:

1. The "expand" parameter was set in a wrong way in the element (object) binding
2. The binding paths in the views were wrong
3. The routes defenition for detail & detail2 had the same patterns, which is not correct
4. There is no need to create multiple ODataModel's, the one, that was instantiated by default (based on your manifest.json config) is mighty enough

I didn't do the refactoring but there is a room for polishing & enhancing this coding and as one said, please refer to the walkthough documentation one more time, there are good examples of the various binding types.. good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe it was something as simple as that. I guess I was blind... :D